# How to find any variation of the number zero; 0, 0.0, 00.00, 0.000, 000.0, etc

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using oracle pl/sql and I have the following sql query.

```
SELECT column_1 FROM table_1
WHERE  column_1 != null
AND    column_1 != ' '
AND    column_1 != '0'
AND    column_1 != '0.0'
AND    column_1 != '00.00'
AND    column_1 != '000.000'
AND    column_1 != '0.000'
AND    column_1 != '000.0'
etc..
etc..
```

As you can see, column_1 is a text field.
What I need to do is remove anything that is any variation of zero, null, or, empty.

Is there anyway to do this without having to list out each individual variation with a WHERE clause?
Something like this is what I was hoping for, but open to any suggestions.

```
SELECT column_1 FROM table_1
WHERE  column_1 != null
AND    column_1 != ' '
AND ConvertToNumberFormat(column_1) != ConvertToNumberFormat(0)
```

Comment: What is ConvertToNumberFormat? It is not a standard Oracle function. Then - are you asking if the ENTIRE string is a form of 0, or perhaps just part of it?

Comment: The "ConvertToNumberFormat" is just a non-existent function I used as a descriptive placeholder to depict what I was trying to accomplish.  I was assuming/hoping there was some actual Oracle function that I could use in replace.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression which matches:

- `^` the start-of-the-string; then
- `\s*` zero-or-more white-space characters; then
- `0*` zero-or-more zero characters; then
- `\.?` zero-or-one dot character; then
- `0*` zero-or-more zero characters; then
- `\s*` zero-or-more white-space characters; then
- `$` the end-of-the-string.

*(You need to match the start and end of the string otherwise it could match sub-strings like `400.03`.)*

Giving the regular expression `^\s*0*\.?0*\s*$`  which you can use like this:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 ( column_1 ) AS
SELECT ' ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '.0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0.0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00.0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4.0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '200.0' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '.03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT ' 00.000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT ' 0000 ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT column_1
FROM   table_1
WHERE  NOT REGEXP_LIKE( column_1, '^\s*0*\.?0*\s*$' );
```

**Output**:

```
COLUMN_1
--------
4.0
200.0
.03
```

You could also create a user-defined function to convert the value to a number and handle any exceptions in the conversion:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ValidateNumber(
  value IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN TO_NUMBER( value );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT column_1
FROM   table_1
WHERE  ValidateNumber( column_1 ) != 0;
```

**Output**:

```
COLUMN_1
--------
4.0
200.0
.03
```

Comment: To whoever downvoted this answer: The downvote without an explanation doesn't help anybody. If you would care to explain what you found wrong with the answer, that would be a lot better. (Alas, I can't say I am holding my breath waiting for that to happen.)

Comment: @mathguy, I agree.  This answer actually seems to answer my question more directly and completely then the other responses. Not sure why anyone would down vote it..

Answer (score 3):

One method would be to simply convert to a number and compare to zero:

```
where cast(column_1 as number) = 0 or column_1 is null or column_1 = ' '
```

That might not work if the column could have non-digit characters.  In that case, you could use a regular expression.  Or even:

```
where regexp_like(column_1, '(0*[.])?[0]+') or column_1 is null or column_1 = ' '
```

Comment: Is `null` needed to be treated separately with `nvl()`?

Comment: Neither of these work. [`CONVERT( char, dest_charset, src_charset )`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620) converts a character string from one character set to another. The regular expression will match every string since all non-null strings contain the empty string which that pattern will match.

Comment: The usual way to escape the period is with a backslash: `\.`

Comment: The first solution (`cast(... as number) or ... = ' '`) is certainly useless. If the value can, in fact, be a single space, and it actually is a single space in any row in the input, then the `cast` will fail and the entire query will simply result in an execution time error.

Comment: @mathguy The regular expression solution is just as wrong as it will not match `0.` but it will match `4.01`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the assignment is to exclude all strings that consist entirely of zero's, at most one decimal point and possibly leading and/or trailing spaces, here is one way to do it, which requires only standard string functions (and therefore should be faster than any regular-expression solution). Note that this also excludes strings made up entirely of spaces (and `NULL`).

```
select * from table_1
where translate(trim(column_1), '.0', '.') <> '.' or trim(column_1) = '.';
```

Explanation: `TRIM()` will remove all leading and trailing spaces. `TRANSLATE()` will change all decimal points to themselves, it will delete (translate to empty string) all 0's, and it will leave all other characters unchanged. If what is left is just one single decimal point, the row should be excluded. Also if what is left is NULL it should be excluded (then the string was all zeros, no decimal point, with or without leading and/or trailing spaces; this includes strings that are all-spaces as well as `NULL`, the empty string.)

Now, this will also exclude a string that's all spaces, a single decimal point, and no zeros on either side of it. I assume that should not be excluded; that's why there's the `OR` part of the `WHERE` clause.

You may be wondering why `TRANSLATE()` needs to translate the decimal point to itself. It doesn't; but you must translate *something* to itself, because Oracle has some very strange ideas about `NULL` and empty string; `TRANSLATE(str, '0', '')` returns `NULL`, it doesn't just zap all the zeros.